# User Model with Listings Rails - How to reach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a Boat Model and its Models such as Brand, Model and Year. I have also User model and I would like to connect them by adding migrations to User model of `boat_id` and I added `belongs_to :boat` and `has_many :boats` to User model. But I can not reach `User.first.boat.name` from the console even though I am able to reach `Boat.first.brand.name`.

When I try `User.first.boat.name`. Console gives an error saying;

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `boat' for #<User:0x0000000665dc30>
```

Btw: Boat Model includes `model_id` `brand_id` and `year_id`.

EDIT1: 
Or should i remove Boat model and add `model_id` `brand_id` and `year_id` to User model directly.

EDIT2:
I would like to be able to reach `User.first.boat.brand.name`  or User.first.boat.year.name`or User.first.boat.model.name`

EDIT3:
Every boat has one brand, year and model. But user can have many boats

EDIT4:
What i will do is; 
User can sign up and login 
Then User press the link list my boat.
He/she saves the boat then the page renders to User Profile
In the User profile I do not know how to get current user boat name year etc. That is why I am confused. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Yes, you need to have user_id in the boats table. This is assuming that each user has many boats, but each boat only has one user. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you post the relevant models and migrations that you've ran upto this point? In your question you say Brand, Model, and Year are attributes yet from your console you're doing `Boat.first.brand.name` which makes it seem like brand is a model.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake yes they are individual models. Corrected

Comment: BTW, the user model cannot have both `belongs_to :boat` and `has_many :boats` at the same time unless you give one of them an alias.

Comment: I am trying to have an `boat_id` at User model, that is why I added `belongs_to`. So I thought I can use `User.first.boat.name`. And yes that is correct.

Comment: If you have a `boat_id` in the `users` table, then each user can only have one boat. However, each boat can have many users, so `boat.users` would make sense. Does this match what you are trying to do?

Comment: Exactly this is what I want to do. But then how i can reach a boat name with a user id 1 lets say?

Comment: I'm confused: you say in the comment above that this is what you want to do (one user can **only** have one boat), but in EDIT3 in the question, you say that one user can have many boats. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry Matt, yes one user can have many boats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused about how Rails associations work in conjunction with how they are stored in the database. If a User can have many boats, then the foreign key needs to be on the `boats` table. Currently you have `boat_id` in the users table, this should be removed and a `user_id` column needs to be added to the boats table as per Matt's answer.

[Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)

To achieve what you're trying to do, you'll need to setup your models in the following manner:

```
class User
  has_many :boats
  ...
end

class Boat
  belongs_to :user # table has a user_id column
  ...
end
```

Then you can access a boat's brand using `user.boats.first.brand.name`

Answer (score 1):

Run `rails generate migration`, then fill in the `change` method as follows:

```
def change
  add_column :boats, :user_id, :integer
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`.

You user model has_many boats, so you need the boats table to refer to users. It's probably worth reading the Rails guide for ActiveRecord associations to get a better feel for how this works: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Comment: Thank you but I have brand_id already in User model `> User.new
 => #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil, remember_digest: nil, activation_digest: nil, activated: false, activated_at: nil, reset_digest: nil, reset_sent_at: nil, boat_id: nil> `

Comment: This all depends on the relations you are trying to build. If you can add the intended outcome to the question i.e. do users have many brands or one, then we can point you towards the correct relations to use.